# Skype will no longer be accepting new Bot registrations?

Tags: azure-bot-service, skype-bots

Find notification at Azure/ Skype chanel seting "As of October 31, 2019 the Skype channel will no longer be accepting new Bot registrations. Current Skype bots will continue to run uninterrupted."

Does it mean my current bot will not work after date?

I have a few Azure Bot Channels which connected with skype.

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says it means. Last month, Skype for Business was deprecated, in that you can no longer add it as a channel. If you look at the channel icons on your bot channels registration, it is no longer there.

Skype will do much of the same, after 31 Oct 2019. The icon will simply not be there for people to add their bots to Skype. BUT! Unlike Skype for Business, which has an actual end date (where bot will no longer work), Skype bots WILL work after that date, you simply will not be able to add any NEW bots to that particular channel.

[image]

Comment: I am confused as hell. Is there a new preferred bot for Skype? And what exactly is a "channel"? We have a bought that talks to a group of our contacts (conversation).

Comment: @Slav - No, there is no new preferred way to build bots for Skype. The deprecation of Skype bots is on the Skype side and not on the Bot Framework side. In the Bot Framework, a channel is any messaging platform you can connect your bot to like Skype, Kik, or Telegram. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels